# Pandas dataframe replace NaN with a nearest minimum value in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a pandas dataframe with column named as 'A_col', and I would like to create new column called 'A_col_fill', which will replace NaN in 'A_col' with a minimum value just prior to it if there is one. The sample output looks like below.

```
            A_col           A_col_fill
0            NaN                 NaN
1            NaN                 NaN
2            NaN                 NaN
3            NaN                 NaN
4            NaN                 NaN
5            NaN                 NaN
6            NaN                 NaN
7           -0.3400             -0.3400
8            NaN                -0.3400
9            NaN                -0.3400
10          -0.1900             -0.1900
11            NaN               -0.1900
12          -0.3700             -0.3700
13          -0.4100             -0.4100
14          -0.3300             -0.3300
15            NaN               -0.4100
16            NaN               -0.4100
17            NaN               -0.4100
18            NaN               -0.4100
19            NaN               -0.4100
20          -1.6500             -1.6500
21          -1.8000             -1.8000
22          -1.5300             -1.5300
23          -1.3500             -1.3500
24            NaN               -1.8000
25          -0.1900             -0.1900
26          -0.1400             -0.1400
28          -0.2100             -0.2100
```

Looks like Dataframe 'fillna' function don't work with case, How can I implement this, any code snippet are highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you add some info on the rules by which it should choose?  it looks like the rule is to choose the minimum of (the preceding contiguous block of [not NaN]) is that correct?

Comment: Shouldn't the value with index 11 be -0.3400? The easiest way to implement this is to put this column into a list and then iterate through this list while keeping track of the running minimum.

Comment: precisely! I like to choose the minimum of the preceding contiguous block to replace NaN

Comment: @MachineLearner, index 11 be -0.1900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will fillna via the following with the minimum value of the last "island" of contiguous rows that contain values.  It should be more accurate and performant than other suggested solutions (at the expense of complication):

- create a column with a group number for each "island" of contiguous values or nans
- get min value for each group; forward fill nan rows with previous min
- fillna of the original column with the new min-per-group column

code:

```
df["group_col"] = np.cumsum(df["A_col"].isna() != df["A_col"].isna().shift())
df["group_min"] = df.groupby("group_col").A_col.transform(min).ffill()
df["output"] = df["A_col"].fillna(df.group_min)
```

result:

```
    A_col  A_col_fill  group_col  group_min  output
0     NaN         NaN          1        NaN     NaN
1     NaN         NaN          1        NaN     NaN
2     NaN         NaN          1        NaN     NaN
3     NaN         NaN          1        NaN     NaN
4     NaN         NaN          1        NaN     NaN
5     NaN         NaN          1        NaN     NaN
6     NaN         NaN          1        NaN     NaN
7   -0.34       -0.34          2      -0.34   -0.34
8     NaN       -0.34          3      -0.34   -0.34
9     NaN       -0.34          3      -0.34   -0.34
10  -0.19       -0.19          4      -0.19   -0.19
11    NaN       -0.19          5      -0.19   -0.19
12  -0.37       -0.37          6      -0.41   -0.37
13  -0.41       -0.41          6      -0.41   -0.41
14  -0.33       -0.33          6      -0.41   -0.33
15    NaN       -0.41          7      -0.41   -0.41
16    NaN       -0.41          7      -0.41   -0.41
17    NaN       -0.41          7      -0.41   -0.41
18    NaN       -0.41          7      -0.41   -0.41
19    NaN       -0.41          7      -0.41   -0.41
20  -1.65       -1.65          8      -1.80   -1.65
21  -1.80       -1.80          8      -1.80   -1.80
22  -1.53       -1.53          8      -1.80   -1.53
23  -1.35       -1.35          8      -1.80   -1.35
24    NaN       -1.80          9      -1.80   -1.80
25  -0.19       -0.19         10      -0.21   -0.19
26  -0.14       -0.14         10      -0.21   -0.14
28  -0.21       -0.21         10      -0.21   -0.21
```

The solution takes milliseconds for a 1M row df on my machine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=100000), columns=["A_col"])
df.loc[df.sample(frac=0.6).index, "A_col"] = np.nan
# code from above
df["group_col"] = np.cumsum(df["A_col"].isna() != df["A_col"].isna().shift())
df["group_min"] = df.groupby("group_col").A_col.transform(min).ffill()
df["output"] = df["A_col"].fillna(df.group_min)
```

Comment: Dude, Nice, clear answer! it's exactly I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
p['A_col'].fillna(np.inf).replace(np.inf,p['A_col'].ffill().cummin())
```

output:

```
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5      NaN
6      NaN
7    -0.34
8    -0.34
9    -0.34
10   -0.19
11   -0.34
12   -0.37
13   -0.41
14   -0.33
15   -0.41
16   -0.41
17   -0.41
18   -0.41
19   -0.41
20   -1.65
21   -1.80
22   -1.53
23   -1.35
24   -1.80
25   -0.19
26   -0.14
28   -0.21
```

Comment: hey it will have horrible time complexity more than O(n^2). Sometime wring simple code is efficient. Pandas/python utils don't' work. It is just a liner iteration over all rows keeping minimum

Comment: seriously?
you didn't see cummin it's an O(n) operation

Comment: I might be missing something, but OP's intended result of index 11 was to be -0.19 not -0.34?

Comment: @anon01 try to check wall time of your code on some dummy data. 
I ran on 10k rows and wall time is 19s for your code.
I ran a liner loop by keeping minimum and the wall time is 42ms.
You should read about time complexity :)

Comment: Thanks! Even, this code snippet is very close what i need, beside the value at index 11 has to be -0.19

Comment: @joe sometime good looking code not always good. Apply for loop and fill. The time complexity. The is horrible of this code. Try to run on big chink of data like a few thousand rows. it just a piece of advice. If you are happy with this then awesome :)

Comment: @ Suryaveer Singh, Agreed! I didn't consider the code time complexity before, I thought a nice and one liner code are always better.

Comment: @SuryaveerSingh you're right I misread this code - it's pretty bad

Comment: Awesome dude! It's very good to accept mistakes to improve ourself :)

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution, just iterate over the column and keep minimum all time and fill Nan value

```
def fill_min(df):
  minx = np.inf
  ans = []
  for val in df['A_Col']:
    if np.isnan(val):
      ans.append(val if np.isinf(minx) else minx)
    else:
      minx = min(minx, val)
      ans.append(val)
  return ans
```

USE:

```
df['A_col_fill'] = fill_min(df)
```